# Combine two 'for' statements into one

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Just a practical Objective-C question here.

I have two `for` loops for two arrays and the same object `SGAdressLabel`:

```
for (SGAdressLabel *tmpLabel in recieversLabels){
    [tmpLabel removeFromSuperview];
}

for (SGAdressLabel *tmpLabel02 in copiesLabels){
    [tmpLabel02 removeFromSuperview];
}
```

How do you combine those two into a single statement and is it necessary? Thanks!

Comment: why would you like to do that? Your code is good as is..

Comment: You are looping over different lists, though. So you should combine those.

Comment: If there are two different arrays, there will be 2 different loops. Are you saying that you want only 1 for loop to do the task of removeFromSuperView? You can go ahead with default for loop syntax for this 

`for(int i=0, j=0; i<[recieversLabels count] || j<[copiesLabels count]; i++, j++)
   {
     if(i<[recieveLabels count])
        [[receiveLabels objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperView];
     // Same if for copiesLabels
   }`
But this is not good code. As KrishnaBhadra said, your code is good as is ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your way is good as is. Since you are working with 2 different arrays, no good will come with trying to iterate using single loop. Or you can append one array into one. But It will not present any new advantages, and confuse the people doing it in future..

Or you can avoid for loop entirely, but iteration is happening underneath..

```
[copiesLabels makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView)];
[receiversLabel makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView)];
```

Answer (score 4):

You could combine the two arrays into one and use that:

```
NSArray *combinedLabels = [recieversLabels arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:copiesLabels];
for (SGAdressLabel *tmpLabel in combinedLabels){
    [tmpLabel removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Note, that objects that are in both arrays, will receive `removeFromSuperview` twice, with this solution.